# Duality between K-theory and K-homology in the non-spin^c case.

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, duality, spin-geometry

I posted this question on Math.SE (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409444/), but got no answer. So I repost it here.

Let M be a closed manifold. Then there is a cap product $K^\ast(M) \times K_\ast(M) \to K_\ast(M)$ between the K-theory of M and its K-homology. For a definition of it one could see my prior question on Math.SE about it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402170/ - take there A = C(M).

Now if M is spin$^c$, it has a fundamental class $[M] \in K_\ast(M)$ and it is well-known that the cap product with $[M]$ induces the Poincare duality $K^\ast(M) \stackrel{\cong}\to K_\ast(M)$. (See also my other question about it: [Duality between K-theory and K-homology in the non-compact, spin$^c$ case](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131378/).)

In the book "Spin Geometry" by Lawson, Michelsohn it is shown (on page 257) that every class in $K_{cpt}(TM) \cong K_0(M)$ is the difference of two Atiyah-Singer operators with coefficients (if M is spin and even dimensional), i.e., this translates to saying that the Poincare duality map is surjective onto $K_0(M)$ in this case.

Then it is written: "For non-spin manifolds, one can argue similarly by using the signature operator with coefficients". This means that there is some class $[D] \in K_\ast(M)$ (the class of the signature operator) such that the cap product with [D] is onto on $K_0(M)$.

Now the question is, if this statement generalizes:

> Is it crucial that it is the signature operator? Could we also take the Euler characteristic operator?
>
> Is there always (i.e., in the non-spin$^c$ case and not only for even dimensional manifolds) a class $[D] \in K_\ast(M)$ such that the cap product with $[D]$ is onto on $K_\ast(M)$ (and not only on $K_0(M)$)?
>
> Maybe even if M is not orientable? Or even when M is not a manifold?
>
> Are there other sufficient conditions besides spin$^c$ such that such a map is injective?

If one of the statements above is true, it would be nice to have some references. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is nicely understood by duality (in the sense of [dualizable objects](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable%20object) in monoidal categories) in the monoidal category [KK](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/KK-theory). The relevant results are collected and referenced on the nLab at *[Poincaré duality algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poincar%C3%A9+duality+algebra)*:

For $X$ a closed manifold equipped with a twist $\chi$ (the class of a [circle 2-bundle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/circle%202-bundle), realized as a $U(1)$bundle gerbe etc., let $C_\chi(X)$ be the corresponding [twisted groupoid convolution C*-algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+algebra), well defined up to Morita equivalence and hence KK-equivalence. This is the $C^\ast$-algebra such that

$$
  KK_\bullet(\mathbb{C}, C_\chi(X)) \simeq K^{\bullet+\chi}(X)
$$

is the $\chi$-[twisted K-theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/twisted%20K-theory) of $X$.

Then here is the statement: The dual object of $C_\chi(X)$ in $(KK, \otimes)$ is

$$
  \left(
     C_\chi\left(X\right)
  \right)^\vee
  \simeq
  C_{-\chi - W_3(T X)}(X)
  \,,
$$

where $W_3(T Q)$ is the [third integral Stiefel-Whitney class](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/integral%20Stiefel-Whitney%20class) of the tangent bundle of $X$.

This formula implies everything in this business.

For instance it implies that $C_\chi(X)$ is self-dual, and hence (since duality in KK is duality between K-homology and K-cohomology) that $X$ exhibits K-Poincaré duality, precisely if $\chi = 0$ and $W_3(T X) = 0$. The latter is precisely the condition of [spin^c structure](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spin%5Ec%20structure).

But you get much more by playing with the formula, and this is I think what you are after. For instance given a map of closed manifolds $i \colon Q \to X$ with $X$ carrying a twist $\chi$ and $Q$ carrying the twist $i^\ast \chi$, we get the corresponding pullback map of twisted convolution algebras

$$
  i^\ast \colon C_\chi(X) \to C_{i^\ast \chi}(Q)
  \,.
$$

Now since both objects have dualty, we can form the corresponding [dual morphism](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dual%20morphism) by the general formula in monoidal categories:

$$
  i_! := (i^\ast)^\vee : (C_{i^\ast \chi}(Q))^\vee \to (C_\chi(X))^\vee
  \,,
$$

hence by the above

$$
  i_! : C_{-i^\ast \chi - W_3(T Q)}(Q)  \to C_{-\chi-W_3(T X)}(X)
  \,.
$$

By just relabelling the original twist for transparency as $\chi \mapsto - \chi - W_3(T X)$ this is equivalently a morphism

$$
  i_! : C_{i^\ast \chi + W_3(N_i Q)}(Q)  \to C_{\chi}(X)
  \,.
$$

(Here $N_i Q$ denotes the normal bundle of $Q$ in $X$ via $i$.)

By postcomposition in KK and using the general relation that $KK(\mathbb{C}, A) \simeq K(A)$ this yields a homomorphism

$$
  i_! : K^{\bullet + i^\ast \chi + W_3(N_i Q)} \to K^{\bullet + \chi}(X)
$$

from the $(i^\ast \chi + W_3(N_i Q))$-twisted K-theory of $Q$ to the $\chi$-twisted K-thory of $X$.

This is the general **twisted Umkehr map** in twisted K-theory. Notice again that it is simply the [dual morphism](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dual%20morphism) of $i^\ast$ in $(KK,\otimes)$.

If now the normal bundle has $Spin^c$-structure then that term drops out, and so on. But in general it is like this.

If here we think of $X$ as the target spacetime for a type II superstring, of $\chi$ as the instanton sector of the [B-field](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/B-field), and of $Q \hookrightarrow X$ as the worldvolume of a D-brane, then the $(i^\ast \chi + W_3(N_i Q))$-twisted K-cocycles on $Q$ are the (underlying instanton sectors of) the [Chan-Paton gauge fields](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chan-Paton%20gauge%20field) subject to the 
[Freed-Witten-Kapustin anomaly cancellation condition](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Freed-Witten+anomaly) and their image under the above twisted Umkehr map is the [D_brane charge](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/D-brane+charge) of the D-brane with that Chan-Paton bundle.

All this just means really: the dual map of $i^\ast$ picks up twists as above. See at *[Poincaré duality algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poincar%C3%A9+duality+algebra)* for citations. All these results go through also for $G$-equivariant twisted K-theory.

Answer (score 13):

For a non-Spin$^c$-manifold, Poincaré duality is best understood in the wrold of KK-theory.  In G. Kasparov's paper on KK-theory and the Novikov conjecture, he shows that for any smooth compact manifold $M$, $C_0(M)$ is Poincaré dual in KK to $C_0(T^*M)$.  In particular, the K-homology of $M$ is isomorphic to the K-theory of $T^*M$.  The isomorphism is induced by the Dolbeault operator on $T^*M$, which is the Dirac operator for a particular Spin$^c$-structure.  This isomorphism can also be identified with the inverse symbol map that constructs a K-homology class from a given symbol in the K-theory of $T^*M$; this is closely related to the Atiyah-Singer index theorem.

If $M$ is not Spin$^c$, then in general the K-homology and K-theory of $M$ are not isomorphic.  Neither the signature operator nor the Euler characteristic operator are relevant here.

We may, however, replace $C_0(T^*M)$ by the Z/2-graded algebra of sections of the Clifford algebra bundle of $M$, Cliff($M$), which has the same K-theory.  A Spin$^c$-structure on $M$ is equivalent to a Morita-equivalence between Cliff($M$) and $C_0(M)$ by an old article by Roger Plymen.  This explains why the K-homology of $M$ is isomorphic to the K-theory of $M$ in the Spin$^c$-case but not in general.

Comment: Hi Ralf. Schön dich hier willkommen zu heissen;)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you will need to add some twisting to obtain Poincare duality. Specifically, if $w\in H^3(X,\mathbb{Z})$ represents the obstruction the your manifold possessing a $spin^c$ structure, then there is a Poincare duality isomorphism $K_*(M)=K^{d-\ast}(X)_{w}$ where $d=\dim M$ and $K^{d-\ast}(X)_w$ is $w$-twisted $K$-theory. This result is proved, for instance, as Proposition 9.2 of Ando-Blumberg-Gepner's paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3004.

Answer (score 4):

There is a paper by Jonathan Rosenberg with the title "The K-homology class of the Euler characteristic operator is trivial" see [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=Rosenberg&s5=trivial&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq), which proves that the only information contained in the class of the Euler characteristic operator is *just* the Euler characteristic, i.e. it lies is the image of $\mathbb{Z}= KO_0(pt) \to KO_0(M)$ induced by the inclusion of the basepoint.